# Convert Data/Time to timezoneoffset in Power Query M

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, m

I have couple of Date/Time parameters
FirstDate = 2/1/2023 12:00:00 AM
EndDate = 5/30/2023 12:00:00 AM

I would like to pass these two variables in the payload of a REST API  call in this below format

**Desired output: {"from":"2023-02-01T00:00:00+00:00","to":"2023-05-31T23:59:59+00:00"}'**

Here is what i have tried that did not work

{""from"":"&DateTime.ToText(FistDate)&",""to"":"&DateTime.ToText(EndDate)&"}}"

The above snippet resolves to this below output & return 400 bad request error

{"from":2/1/2023 12:00:00 AM,"to":5/30/2023 12:00:00 AM}}

Can anyone from Power Query code to cover the Date/time parameters in to the above Desired Output format 9in bold)

Comment: I think i found the issue & fixed the problem too  . Missed single quotes {""from"":'"&DateTime.ToText(FistDate)&"',""to"":'"&DateTime.ToText(EndDate)&"'}}",

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a Format string with [DateTime.ToText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-totext).

There's an example of this in the Incremental Refresh Docs:

```
strRangeStart = DateTime.ToText(RangeStart,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Culture="en-US"]),
```

[Incremental refresh and real-time data for datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview)